# How can I dynamically remove / replace a ReactJS class at runtime in the browser?

Tags: dynamic, reactjs, webpack-hmr

I'm playing around with the idea of a web based IDE for building React applications.  Basically the user defines and modifies the `class` entirely within the browser.

I know I can create a class using `React.createClass` but how can I delete it or redefine it when the user makes modifications to the class.

I know Webpack HMR does this but how can I do it entirely in the browser?

Comment: Can you run that portion of your code in an IFrame? This would allow you to start from scratch every time a modification was made.

Comment: I don't think an `IFRAME` would work.  What would the `src` be?  The classes are dynamically defined not a file on disk.  Also, I'm looking to replace an existing class's implementation but keep its state like HMR does.